# Selecting ever LI that comes BEFORE a ul

Tags: jquery

I have a series of nested `<ul>`s for my navigation:

```
<ul> 
 <li> 
  <ul>
   <li>
     </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
```

I am trying to figure out, by using jQuery add class method, how to select and add a class to every `<li>` *before* an `<ul>`

Comment: You have malformed html there.

Comment: Why must use the parent selecting? Is it possible to label some class to the target dom element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul').parent('li').addClass('test');
```

Works if you fix the html

```
<ul> 
   <li> 
      <ul>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: <script>
$("li ul ").before ().addClass("has-dropdown");
</script>I was trying this

Comment: `$("li > ul").parent()` should be the same

Comment: thanks Balint, weird why the before class was not working or doesn't work as well as the parent!

Comment: `before()` is for inserting new elements and not for traversing the DOM tree